# compiling error when compiling android platform calendar app

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to study the calendar example and found the following source code.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/android-sdk-4.4.2_r1

However, I have many errors when I tried to compile the example. 
Any suggestions when compiling examples from this web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those applications are meant to be built within the context of a full AOSP checkout. You'll want to look at http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html and http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html for how to grab the full AOSP source and build things.

Comment: The link seems targeting linux system. Can this be done on Windows?

Comment: I guess I need to set up a linux system. What is the smallest linux OS I can use for Android development?